# How do I deal with misalignment in cabinet doors resulting in gaps?

Tags: doors, hinges, gap

I hired some contractors to do some carpentry work, but after months the gaps between the doors are appearing and it looks ugly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Because of the gap, it has become safe haven for cockroach and lizards.

Here is the hinge that's used in all the carpentry work.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this and make sure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: If you have cockroaches and lizards, I feel like some carpentry is the least of your worries.

Comment: needs cabinet magnets

Comment: Mazura - Thanks,that's a wonderful idea but I have so many cabinet or wardrobe doors. Wondering how many cabinet magnets , I will have to buy and install.

Comment: @Huesmann - I'm hoping to cut down their access to the cabinets and wardrobes. It just spoils the things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those hinges have some adjustment screws, as you can see:

[image]

#1 moves the door horizontally (when closed). Use it to adjust the gap between doors as well as the relative heights of the doors.

#2 lets you move the door closer to and further away from the cabinet. It would likely solve the misalignment shown in your photos. Loosen it slightly, slide the hinge body in or out, and snug it back up.